# Changing the UI of a webform when the browser language changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to change the location of some controls of a webform when the page is opened in a different language. That is I simply need to Localize the GUI of the Webform too along with the text of the webform.

Comment: Ok seems like my text was not clear enough to explain. Lets understand it like this. Suppose we have a web application which is localized in Frech. Now the problem is with the UI. Lets say there is a button which has text Select All in English but when the french version is used the text gets converted to Sélectionner tout which is larger than Select All and hence the GUI gets affected. So I need to change the UI as well when the french version is used.

Answer (score 1):

Check the property, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

This will give u the culture of use.

And depending on this value redirect to the web page you want.

Comment: Oh so do i need to create another page for that?

Comment: No, you can change the position of the controls dynamically.

Comment: Thats what i need to know. How the position and size of the conrols be changed dynamically?

Comment: @Nadeem; position in what sense? left to right and right to left?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: When text gets converted to Sélectionner tout from Select All, I need the button to be large enough to fit this text

Comment: On server side, there are options- 

1) If you want to do it globally for all pages, use Themes. 

If not 

1) Use Style property of the control to modify the style attributes. 

2) If you are using Css, then there is a CssClass property of server controls, which u can update with new css depending on the locale. 

3) if u want to do it for all the controls on the page, then register a CSS using RegisterStartupBlock for that page.

Comment: Okay this makes sense. I tried to load a css class dynamically and it seems to be working.

Comment: Thats good, it worked for u!! You can close this question by marking it as answer.